# Ionic tab app throws error on new tab add

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to add tabs in my exiting Ionic app:

directory structure:

```
- src/pages/admin/dashboard
- src/pages/admin/tabs
- ..../tabs/ tabs.module.ts , tabs.page.html , tabes.page.ts , tabs.router.module.ts
```

**tabs.module.ts code:**

```
import { DashboardPage } from '../dashboard/dashboard.page';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        TabsPageRoutingModule,
        DashboardPage
    ],
    declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

**tabs.router.module.ts code:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                outlet: 'dashboard',
                loadChildren: '../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule'
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

Tried all sources googles its changes as per the error message
but still stuck with below error message:

```
core.js:12501 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected directive 'DashboardPage' imported by the module 'TabsPageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
Error: Unexpected directive 'DashboardPage' imported by the module 'TabsPageModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

- app environment ionic 4

Thanks for any help or hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your error code:

```
Unexpected directive 'DashboardPage' imported by the module 'TabsPageModule'.
```

In **tabs.module.ts** you need to import the PageModule instead of the page itself.
So change *DashboardPage* to *DashboardPageModule*.